# Extracting data from a List<Server> userList using Lamda expressions

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I have two List importServerList,currServerList

where I want to replace the duplicates using filter method.

Server POJO

```
public class Server {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="serverName")
    private String serverName;      

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "server",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    //@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    //@JoinColumn(name="server_id", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private List<IPAddress> ipaddresses;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getServerName() {
    return serverName;
    }

    public void setServerName(String serverName) {
    this.serverName = serverName;
    }
    public void setIpaddresses(List<IPAddress> ipaddresses) {
        this.ipaddresses = ipaddresses;
    }

    public List<IPAddress> getIpaddresses() {
        return ipaddresses;
    }

    public String getPrimaryIpAddress() {
        return ipaddresses.stream()
            .filter(IPAddress::isPrimary)
            .findAny()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("there should be a primary address"))
            .getIpaddress();
    }

}
```

Here is my IPAddress POJO

```
public class IPAddress {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="ipaddress")
    private String ipaddress;

    @Column(name="primaryIP")
    private boolean primary;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "server_id")
    private Server server;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIpaddress() {
        return ipaddress;
    }

    public void setIpaddress(String ipaddress) {
        this.ipaddress = ipaddress;
    }

    public boolean isPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(boolean primary) {
        this.primary = primary;
    }

    public Server getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    public void setServer(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }


}
```

Here **primary ipaddress** is unique for each server

Now I want a list without **Mutation** or changing the data in original list therefore using **functional** approach.

I am retrieving new list which has a serverList data + removing redundant data from currServerList

I tried this thing

```
Set<String> primaryIpAddresses = currServerList.stream()
                    .map(Server::getPrimaryIpAddress)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            List<Server> filteredList=importServerList.stream()
                    .filter(s->primaryIpAddresses.contains(s.getPrimaryIpAddress())?s:currlistserverObject)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I guess it might work correctly but don't know what to add in `s:currlistserverObject`

**Objective:** to get new List which has all Servers from importServerList and currServerList but if there is a clash or same ipaddress in both then update server from importServerList since server name might differ so I want to update importServerList server in new list

Comment: can you may be simplify this problem? can't tell what you want to do or achieve

Comment: I have two List<Server> as stated above but if ipaddress of serverList is same as ipaddress of currServerList then take Server from serverList in filtered or new list which is also type List<Server> so we have to collect a list of server from both list but take server from serverList if primary ip is equal in both list

Comment: read what you just wrote yourself, I read it 3 times, still have a hard time understanding, sorry. Might be me here, don't know

Comment: its like server a,b,c in serverList and d,e,f in currServerList check if any of the primary ip address of serverList matches with primary address of currServerList then return server from serverList else add all.  It's like a union but adding only from serverList if there is a equal server

Comment: @Eugene sorry for making it complex though whatever I asked above the answer I edited of PankajSinghal will work for me

Comment: no worries at all, if I did not understand does not mean everyone else would not too; so you got your answer than... if such case upvote and accept it

Comment: Yes but I edited it myself and in new filtered list I am getting null id since ImportServerList is not from db therefore need to set id from currServerList where ipaddress is equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Server> newList = new ArrayList<>(importServerList);

Set<String> primary = importServerList.stream()
        .map(Server::getPrimaryIpAddress)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<Server> temp = currServerList
        .stream()
        .filter(server -> !primary.contains(server.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

newList.addAll(temp);
```

Comment: Perfect this is what I was saying interchanging with list will work but you did a little wrong remove temp with newList and dont take it as Set rather List

Comment: no. `newList` contains all `importServerList`. You need to add the temp inside `newList` inorder to keep the data from `importServerList`

Comment: see my update in your answer and tell what is wrong in that?

Comment: I've already added importServerList in the first line. see `List<Server> newList = new ArrayList<>(importServerList);`

Comment: but tell me what's wrong in my edit of your answer please look I removed all importServerList servers common in currServerList over stream of currServerList then I added the whole serverList at last

Comment: Pankaj if I want to set the server id in filtered list where primary ipaddress are same in both list then can you tell what will be the expression

Comment: filteredList.stream().forEach(s->s.setId(currServerList.stream()
     .filter(server->server.getId()))); // it goes like this but right now its wrong

Comment: @Plootus Does your edit work for you? If yes, I'll accept it

Comment: A little problem I am having while using this code....is that it adds the server of currServerList also though it's replacing the duplicates if found but it does add server of currServerList rather it should replace if found importServerList

Comment: What if I set only the id of duplicates in importServerList then I update in db therefore with same id only those items will be replaced rather bringing all db data and updating all items for the one's who's server primary ip address is not same

Answer (score 0):

Your filter block isn't correct.  If I understand your problem correctly(which as @Eugene mentioned is not so clear) this is what you need

```
Set<String> primaryIpAddresses = currServerList.stream()
            .map(Server::getPrimaryIpAddress)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<Server> filteredList=importServerList.stream()
            .filter(!s->primaryIpAddresses.contains(s.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

filteredList.addAll(currServerList);
```

In your question you said serverList and currServerList. But the variables are named currServerList & importServerList. This is quite confusing. I believe by importServerList you mean serverList

Comment: yes it is maybe confused with the variables.....if interchange in all your code with currServerList with importServerList.. it will work fine I guess because I don't want to all currServerList rather importServerList.....the whole operation is about replacing the duplicates of currServerList which are servers in database with new servers which is importServerList. It is a override operation in server update